# How can I show the same page (a form of inputs) with the errors in a restfull api in java?

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, redirect, error-handling

I have an input form which has many inputs.When click the submit button I want to save the data to my mongodb but check first if the name exist or not.If exist I don't want to save the data and redirect the same page with the error (ex.This product code you insert is alredy exist.Please insert a different one) but I don t want to use spring form because I want my backent to be restfull and be independent of the front end.So my question is how to do that without using the "spring form and jsp manner".

Comment: A restful API doesn't return pages. It returns data. In your case, it should return a 400 Bad Request response. And the frontend (which would typically be written in JavaScript and send AJAX requests) would simply intercept this response, show an error to the user, and would simply stay on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

You could return the error response from your REST endpoint and handle it in your javascript.

For rest api practices and how to return error code read [DOC](https://blog.restcase.com/rest-api-error-codes-101/).

Suppose you have a form  and have a div to show the error .You could do something like the following in your javascript to show the error in the error div whenever an error message is returned from the rest endpoint, or have message according to the response status.

```
<span id="errorDiv"></span>
....

<form>

</form>

jQuery("#save").click(function () {
  if (jQuery('#form').jVal()) {
    jQuery.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "save",
      dataType: "html",
      data: formData,
      success: function (response) {
        jQuery("#usergrid").trigger("successMessageId");
        clear();
        alert("Details saved successfully!!!");
      },
    error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
     var msg = '';
     if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
         msg = 'Not connect.\n Verify Network.';
     } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
         msg = 'Requested page not found. [404]';
     } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
         msg = 'Internal Server Error [500].';
     } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
         msg = 'Requested JSON parse failed.';
     } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
         msg = 'Time out error.';
     } else if (exception === 'abort') {
         msg = 'Ajax request aborted.';
     } else {
         msg = 'Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText;
    }
   $("#errorDiv").html(msg);
   },
      }
    });
  }
});
```